# translationY does not perform slide up animation when view state is changed from disable to enable

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-animation

I need to `disable/enable` a view by slide down and up.

I used following code and it successfully slide down (move view from top to bottom) the view and disables it.

```
public void slideDown(View view){


        view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
               view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Now i want to use the `bottom up/ slide up` animation when user enables the view. So i used following code, but it does not perform `bottom up` animation, and enables view directly.

```
  view.animate().translationY(0).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to move  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); to onAnimationEnd?

Comment: @W0rmH0le : yes i am getting a little face effect when user enable the view.